# Translate a Java Class containing a Generics to Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I'm developing an app where multiple classes have images to better identify themselves, such as users, items, damage and etc...

So I'm creating a Class that accepts generics class so I can relate each of this classes to the Images that I'm saving. It's a one-to-many relationship of course, an item may have a max of 4 images but each image can have 1 item for example.

That's my class file:

```
public class Image<T> implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private byte[] image;
    private T entity;
    private Long entityId;
    private int index;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @AuditableField(value= "image", encoder = ByteArrayFieldEncoder.class)
    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public T getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

    public void setEntity(T entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public Long getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(Long entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    @AuditableField
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof Image)) return false;
        Image image = (Image) obj;
        return Objects.equals(id, image.id);
    }
}
```

But what I'm struggling to do is how to build the XML code for this class, does anyone knows how can I do that? If it's even possible...